# how to decide this language

Tags: turing-machines

My problem is to build a machine that decide this language:

{〈A, w〉| A is a DFA and w is the longest word in L(A)}

I know that DFA has finite states and eventually for every word that i simulate on A ,i would get an answer (yes/no) and know if w is in L(A).

In order to know if w is biggest can i build a TM M that Non deterministically guess a word grater than W and reject if A accept it?
otherwise M accept.

Comment: Your proposed Turing machine would not work. A nondeterministic Turing machine accepts if **at least one** of its computation paths accepts. Your TM would accept as long as there **exists** a word longer than $|w|$ that **is not** in $L(A)$. You need to accept iff there **does not exists** a word longer that $|w|$ that **is** in $L(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Detect whether there is a cycle in the DFA containing a state $q$ such that $q$ is reachable from the initial state and $q$ can reach a final state (this can be done by deleting all states of $A$ that do not satisfy these requirements and looking for a cycle in the resulting graph).

If the answer is affirmative then $L(A)$ is infinite and you can reject without even examining $w$.

If the answer is negative then the pumping lemma ensures that all words in $L(A)$ have length at most $n-1$, where $n$ is the number of states of $A$ (since the path traced by any word in $L(A)$ having length at least $n$ must traverse some state two or more times).
Then you can explicitly test all words in $\bigcup_{i=|w|+1}^{n-1} \Sigma^i$  (or $\bigcup_{i=|w|}^{n-1} \Sigma^i \setminus  \{w\}$ if you are trying to decide whether $w$ is the **unique** longest word in $L(A)$).